# Creating a counter for a very large hash (rails)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I'm trying to parse out some information from Jira's rest API using this gem: https://github.com/sumoheavy/jira-ruby

I am creating a reporting app that will count the number of times a specific 'assignee' resolves an issue in a specific project.

The hash would look like this...

```
[#<JIRA::Resource::Issue:329487 @attrs={'key'=>'value','key'=>'value', "fields"=> {project=>{'key'=>'value'}, assignee=>{'key'=>'value'}}
```

I specifically need to get the value of the assignee, and the value of the project, then somehow get them in a table that would list out each assignee, and how many completed issues they have in each project.

The issues that are showing up in this are only completed issues due to the query that I'm using, so don't worry about that, just need to parse this out and count it using some method in a model.

I can currently make a nice parsed table (doesn't get me the info I need) by using this in the view...

```
`<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Count</th>
    <th>Issue Key</th>
    <th>Summary</th>
    <th>Time Estimate</th>
    <th>Reporter</th>
    <th>Assignee</th>
  </thead>
<% @issues.each_with_index do |issue, index| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= index + 1 %>  </td>
    <td><%= issue.key %> </td>
    <td><%= issue.fields['summary'] %>  </td>
    <td><%= issue.fields['aggregatetimeestimate'] %> </td>
    <td><%= issue.fields['reporter'].values[4] %> </td>
  <% if issue.fields['assignee'].present? %>
    <td><%= issue.fields['assignee'].values[4] %></td>
  <% else %>
    <td>N/A</td>
  <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>`
```

What I would rather see... Is a table that has the different assignees as the rows, and the different projects as the columns, then the number of issues that have that certain assignee per project, then a grand total on the right.  So I need to iterate through all of the assignees, combine all of the assignees that are the same, and tally the count per project in the columns.

I would prefer not to use activerecord, as I'm not saving to a database.  The database is the information being retrieved through the API, so it is constantly changing.

Remember that the projects hash, and the assignee hash are hashes of their own, and each one is several levels deep in the entire issues hash.  {Issues hash => { fields hash=>{project hash}{assignee hash}}}

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Maybe a good way to start is to grab all of the [assignee].value[4] strings and create a new array with those values, then use:
     def self.assignee_count(issue)
      issue.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,e| h[e] +=1 ; h}
     end'

How would I implement that from my .each do loop?  Then how would I associate with the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# Controller
# {Assignee => {Project => Issues closed} }
@assignee_hash = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = Hash.new(0) }
@projects = Array.new
@issues.each do |issue|
    # I'm not familiar with the structure of the assignee/project
    # hashes here (and 'key'=>'value' isn't too descriptive),
    # but these next 2 lines should be modified to access whatever 
    # value you want to identify the assignee and project by
    assignee = issue.fields['assignee'].??
    project  = issue.fields['project'].??
    @projects.push project unless projects.include? project
    @assignee_hash[assignee][project] += 1
end

#View
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Assignee</th>
    <% @projects.each do |project| %>
      <th><%= project %></th>
    <% end %>
    <th>Total</th>
  </thead>
  <% @assignee_hash.each do |assignee, project_hash| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= assignee %></td>
      <% @projects.each do |project| %>
        <td><%= project_hash[project] %></td>
      <% end %>
      <td><%= project_hash.values.reduce(:+) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: You nailed it.  Had to add an if statement to see if assignee was present, but there was no way for you to know that that was needed.

Now on to adding totals for every column on the bottom...

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Hey Looby, I have an extension to this question, if you're willing to help.  I would really appreciate any input you have.  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17221868/working-with-three-hash-values-in-rail-html-table